# How to use custom laser scan message fro gmapping? I am using YD LIDAR. Can I publish the scan message to another ropic than /scan?

Tags: ros

How to use a custom laser scan message for `gmapping`? I am using `YD LIDAR`. Can I publish the scan message to another rostopic than `/scan`?

Publishing the custom message to the same topic is not appropriate, and if I publish to another topic, how can I use it for `gmappping` and navigation package?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to change the actual `gmapping` repo or create a node to convert from you custom message type to `sensor_msgs::LaserScan`. Because if it is a custom message, the `void laserCallback(const sensor_msgs::LaserScan::ConstPtr& scan)` from the [node](https://github.com/ros-perception/slam_gmapping/blob/melodic-devel/gmapping/src/slam_gmapping.h) won't be able to handle.

Mapping to another topic can be achieved by doing remap, either in the launch file of the `laserscan` publisher or the subscriber

Answer (score 0):

What exactly do you mean by *custom laser scan message*? A custom message type or just another topic with a `sensor_msgs::LaserScan`.

If you really mean a custom type and you use ros2, then you can probably use the new [TypeAdapter Feature](https://docs.ros.org/en/foxy/Releases/Release-Humble-Hawksbill.html#support-type-adaption-for-publishers-and-subscriptions). If you use an older version then you have to convert the message to a known format like `sensor_msgs::LaserScan` or `sensor_msgs::PointCloud2`.

If you just have a second scanner and would like to use this data as well, then have a look at [one of my questions on ros answers](https://answers.ros.org/question/391527/how-to-use-multiple-laser-scanners-for-slam-and-navigation/).
You can use [ira_laser_tools](https://github.com/iralabdisco/ira_laser_tools) to merge scans into one new scan message or a combined point cloud, but unfortunately, there isn't a great solution. To my knowledge ros_cartographer is currently the only slam package that can handle multiple scanners as input.